# Deploying a Solution with multiple projects on IIS7 - Missing DLLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, dll, iis-7, publishing

I'm trying to publish a solution that contains several projects -one of them is MVC- to IIS7.
When the MVC project is published and some views are being accessed I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This happens because the view I'm trying to access is calling a function in another project in that solution and needs this library!

but this library is not contained in the MVC project!

I was able to solve it by referencing that DLL in the MVC project! but I need another solution, because it doesn't make sense to reference every single DLL in all the other projects!
I'm using the "Web Deploy"  publish option for the MVC project, is there another way that I can publish it and make it work without referencing all the DLLs from all the other projects?

Comment: You don't need to reference those files in your MVC project but instead just deploy them as well.

Comment: The Problem is, all the other projects are referenced by the MVC project and configured to be released as DLLs!
So there's no Publish option for them!

Comment: It doesn't mean that if a DLL is referenced in a project (i.e. Proj1) that is in turn referenced by another project (i.e. MVC proj) that you need to reference that DLL in MVC. You only need to do that if you use any of the functionality (method) from the DLL directly in the MVC project. Now, even if you do not reference that DLL you need to add it to your deployment. Again no need to reference it in the MVC project.

Comment: I'm with you on that.
The problem is, these projects are configured to be built as "Class Library" and they are referenced as DLLs in the MVC project.
when one of these projects is selected, the Publish option is not even there! What should I do?

Comment: Can anybody help me find a way to enable referencing the DLLs referenced by the Class library project when this Class Library is referenced in another project!?

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on how to deploy assemblies that are not referenced by your MVC project directly:
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Basically you need to create a folder in your project called _bin_deployableAssemblies and add your assemblies to it. They will get deployed with the website.

Here is a quote from the article:

> So here’s the kicker. If you’re building a web application, and you
>   need an assembly deployed but don’t want it referenced and don’t want
>   it checked into the bin directory, you can simply add this folder
>   yourself and put your own assemblies in here.